# How to add anotations to points created with matplotlib.patches.circle?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I've got an image with circles plotted on top using `matplotlib.patches.Circle` which worked fine here:

[image: Circles on top of my example image]

I was just wondering if it is possible to add annotations to the circles using the same class Circle as in the second image (two of the circles have manually added annotations 1 and 2)

[image: annotated circles]

I know there is a possibility to add a legend to the circles but I need to have the information next to the circles and not as a separate box.

Comment: I do not see a difference between the two images, but you may look at annotations: [Annotation tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/annotations.html), [annotation examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html).

Comment: I see, Annotation method would solve the problem just fine thank you! And sorry about the not so helpful images.